# Custom route and form get parameters

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have the following route set up

```
routes.jobSearch.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.jobSearch.route = "job/:sector/search/:sectorID/:subSectorID/:regionID/:jobTypeID/:ignore/:keywords/:page"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.module = "site"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.controller = "job"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.action = "search"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.keywords = ""
routes.jobSearch.regs.sector = "\w+"
```

And aslo I have this Zend_Form which provides search interface. But when I submit the form, the url becomes

```
http://localhost/job/all/search?search_sector=1&search_sub_sector=0&world_area=0&job_type=0&search_submit=Submit+Query&keywords=
```

and because of this my custom route is not matched. So is there a way to do this?

[EDIT]
Here is the new route which didn't work either

```
routes.jobSearch.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.jobSearch.route = "job/:sector/search/:search_sector/:search_sub_sector/:world_area/:job_type/:search_submit/:keywords"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.module = "site"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.controller = "job"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.action = "search"
```

[EDIT ref:@Jani]
This is my route now

```
routes.jobSearch.route = "job/:sector/search/:subSectorID/:regionID/:jobTypeID/:search_submit/:keywords/:page"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.module = "site"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.controller = "job"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.action = "search"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.sector = "all"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.subSectorID = "0"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.regionID = "0"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.jobTypeID = "0"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.search_submit = "Submit+Query"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.keywords = ""
routes.jobSearch.defaults.page = "1"
```

and it matches correctly. At least I get the search result page. But all passes parameters are set to their defaults. So if I hit this url
http://localhost/job/pharmaceutical/search?subSectorID=1&regionID=1&jobTypeID=1&search_submit=Submit%20Query&keywords=drugs and if I do `var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams())` I expect to see

```
array
  'sector' => string 'pharmaceutical' (length=14)
  'module' => string 'site' (length=4)
  'controller' => string 'job' (length=3)
  'action' => string 'search' (length=6)
  'subSectorID' => string '1' (length=0)
  'regionID' => string '1' (length=1)
  'jobTypeID' => string '1' (length=1)
  'search_submit' => string 'Submit+Query' (length=12)
  'keywords' => string 'drugs' (length=0)
  'page' => string '1' (length=1)
```

but what I get is

```
array
  'sector' => string 'pharmaceutical' (length=14)
  'module' => string 'site' (length=4)
  'controller' => string 'job' (length=3)
  'action' => string 'search' (length=6)
  'subSectorID' => string '0' (length=0)
  'regionID' => string '0' (length=1)
  'jobTypeID' => string '0' (length=1)
  'search_submit' => string 'Submit+Query' (length=12)
  'keywords' => string '' (length=0)
  'page' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: how are you setting your form action?

Comment: form action is the current page url. So for the example above, action is `job/all/search`

Comment: and the method would be set to 'get'?

Comment: yes, it's get. I need GET because there is a pagination on the search results page as well.

Comment: It looks like your form is not submitting the correct parameters. Either your element names need to be changed to reflect what you want your url's to look like or change your route to match the parameters you're sending. Your first route paramter is sectorId and your form is submitting search_sector. See the issue?

Comment: aren't they just place holders. Well, I changed my routes (edited the question) and still no luck

Comment: put your form up. Are you matching all the parameters with $this->getRquest()->getParams()

Comment: no they are not just placeholders, they usually map to the keys in the getParams() array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your route does not match at all.

The routes in ZF only match the path - not GET params / query string.

The path you're using is: `/job/all/search`

Your route only matches a path like: `job/:sector/search/:sectorID/:subSectorID/:regionID/:jobTypeID/:ignore/:keywords/:page`

In order for your route to match just `/job/all/search`, you need to provide default values for all the other parameters in the route, or create a route which match that path.

Match the path:

```
routes.jobSearch.route = "/job/:sector/search"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.module = "site"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.controller = "job"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.action = "search"
```

Or, give defaults:

```
routes.jobSearch.route = "job/:sector/search/:sectorID/:subSectorID/:regionID/:jobTypeID/:ignore/:keywords/:page"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.module = "site"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.controller = "job"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.action = "search"
routes.jobSearch.defaults.keywords = ""
routes.jobSearch.defaults.sectorId = ""
routes.jobSearch.defaults.subSectorID = ""
routes.jobSearch.defaults.regionID = ""
routes.jobSearch.defaults.jobTypeID = ""
routes.jobSearch.defaults.ignore = ""
routes.jobSearch.defaults.page = ""
routes.jobSearch.regs.sector = "\w+"
```

In order for the form to work as you described, you need to use `getQuery()` (or `getPost()` if you use POST form) from the request, not `getParam()`.

`getParam()` defaults to router parameters first, then get, then post.

If you want to use the route params as defaults, you could do something along the lines of...

```
$foo = $this->_request->getQuery('foo', $this->_getParam('foo'));
```

This way if 'foo' exists in GET, you get that first, and if not, the result of `_getParam` becomes the value.

(`_getParam` is an alias for `request->getParam()`)

Comment: So if he matched /job/:sector/search he could still pass any other parameters in the url? the documentation is not real clear on how all of this works(at least I'm not getting it all).

Comment: @Jani thanks! I think we are getting there. Please see the edit in my question

Comment: @boosis getParam will load parameters in the incorrect order, using route params first, and get only after that. I edited the answer to explain it further

Comment: @RockyFord ZF routes ignore any GET parameters. They do not affect routing. If you want to pass an arbitrary amount of parameters in the URL, you need to use the `*` wildcard (eg. `/job/:sector/search/*`, after which `/job/all/search/foo/bar` would set parameter 'foo' to value 'bar')